# Is there a way I can replicate local database to live database in realtime

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a library management system. When I connect the tables directly to the live database, everything just become very slow. Is there a way I can use my local database, and then at the end of the day update the live database, or even better update it periodically?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Comment: in that way, you will be the only one who works on db. Then if is only for development, just do all project locally. In live mode if other users updated the db, then is almost impossible to sync properly (local work and users updates). As you said here is only deployment (from dev to live).

Comment: Replication works much better and faster if it the servers are always connected.  Is there only one "local" server and only one "live" server?  Or are there lots of "locals" and they are often offline?